# git: exclude files from remote

Tags: git, playframework, git-remote

I have a Play Scala app which has two remotes, one for source, and another for deployment. Deployment needs the ./target directory but I want to keep the source remote clean of build files. Is it possible to have only the source remote ignore the target directory?

thanks!

Comment: I don't know about the Play framework but is it a good idea at all to use a versioning tool to distribute your build artifacts?

Comment: Quite a few cloud PaaS offerings (heroku, openshift, etc) use pushes to a git remote for deployment.

Comment: But I do agree I don't like having build artifacts in the repo which is why I want them only tracked for deployment :)

Comment: From where I stand, we also "use pushes to a git remote for deployment". But we don't push the build artifacts through git, we push just the source, as usual, and our build/deploy server picks that up from git, produces the build artifact, and deploys as appropriate. I'm just saying, maybe you should look past git for a better solution. How do other Play Scala apps usually do it?

Comment: You can make a war and deploy that to a container, OpenShift does support JBoss and Tomcat so I could deploy that way. I was following this example https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart. On heroku pushing through git is the only way https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play#deploy-your-application-to-heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `.gitignore` file to your repository (root), e.g. something like the following:

```
# Ignore target directory
target
```

Edit: Sorry, too fast on the trigger there. This will ignore the target file for both remotes. To include some files in your deployment remote, you should probably use different branches.

One branch for your deployment and one for your source. Whenever you deploy, merge differences from source branch to deployment branch. In the deployment branch, your `.gitignore` file could look differently.

Answer (score 1):

What about having a *deploy* branch, whose upstream would be your remote deployment branch, and where you don't ignore the *build/* directory?
You would then have to merge your development branch into *deploy* before each deployement.